# How do I pass an activerecord association as a string to a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following associations:

User has_many Ultimate_Source

User has_many Budget_Source

How do I create the following method:

```
def foo(source)
  user = User.find(1)
  user.source.id
end
```

such that

```
foo(ultimate_sources)
```

returns:

```
user.ultimate_sources.id
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if source == :ultimate_sources or source == :budget_sources then the following should work.

user.send(source).id

if source is a string you can always convert it to a symbol using source.to_sym.

The send method takes a symbol representing the name of a method and sends the message to that object to execute that method and return what the method returns.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `.send`:

```
def foo(source)
  user = User.find(1)
  user.send(source.to_s).id
end
```

Or the method `.try` (will not raise a NoMethodError if `source` is not a method of User):

```
def foo(source)
  user = User.find(1)
  user.try(source.to_s).id
end
```

---

**But I really hope** that `source` is not something coming from the user's input. What if I send `delete` as value of `source` variable? It would delete the user ...

I highly recommend you to limit the possible methods, in your case it could be something like this:

```
def foo(source)
  user = User.find(1)
  user.try("#{source.gsub('_sources', '')}_sources").try(:id)
end
```

This code version protects you to send `destroy` as the `source` value:

```
foo('ultimate_sources') # => user.ultimate_sources.id
foo('destroy') # => nil
foo('destroy_sources') # => nil
foo('budget') # => user.budget_sources.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also put in a guard clause to be safe.

```
def foo(source)
   return if (source != 'ultimate_sources') || (source != 'budget_sources')

   user = User.find(1)
   user.send(source).id
end
```